# c# regex to replace on last occurence of pattern

Tags: c#, regex, string

I built an extension to convert HTML formatted text to something better for a list view.  It removes all HTML tags except it replaces `<h>` and `<p>`s with `<br />` to keep readability on the list view.  It also shortens the text for longer posts.  I put it on my razor view with `HTML.Raw(model.text)`.

```
public static string FixHTML(string input, int? strLen)
        {
            string s = input.Trim();
            s = Regex.Replace(s, "</p.*?>", "<br />");
            s = Regex.Replace(s, "</h.*?>", "<br />");
            s = s.Replace("<br />", "*ret$990^&");
            s = Regex.Replace(s, "<.*?>", String.Empty);
            s = Regex.Replace(s, "</.*", String.Empty);
            s = s.Replace("*ret$990^&", "<br />");
            int i = (strLen ?? s.Length);
            s = s.Substring(0,(i > s.Length ? s.Length : i));
            return(s);
        }
```

PROBLEM: if the last character gets cut off mid `<br />` it messes up the displayed text.  Example it gets cut off at `blah blah blah <br` then the display isnt nice.  How can I use REGEX (or even string replace) to find only the last occurence of `<b`.... and only if it doesnt have a closing `>`.

I was thinking of something like:

```
s = string.Format(s.Substring(0, s.Length-6) + Regex.Replace(s.Substring(s.Length - 6), "<.*", string.Empty));
```

That will probably work but my whole converter seems like it is using a to of code to do something that should be relatively simple.

How can I do this?

Comment: Using regex to parse HTML is not recommended.

Comment: Is there anything that IS recommended to "clean" HTML?  What I am doing above works, but I agree its not pretty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: I would suggest a library such as [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) to parse through and change your HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, "(<|<b|<br|<br/)$", "", RegexOptions.None);
```

Comment: An alternate regex that would catch all incomplete html tags (not just `br`) at the end of a string would be `"<[^>]*$"`.

Comment: @Rudism - definitely a good solution, the only problem might be if the "<" character appeared in the text not as part of a tag